# Decorator for functions with positional arguments, with commonly named argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, keyword-argument

I have a set of functions/methods that all have different set of positional arguments and- in some cases - keyword arguments too, but share one string argument named *lane_type*. It may be either positional or keyword argument.
Due to design flaw (guilty as charged) the same value in different places may have capital letters in the string. Therefore for comparisons I have to convert it to lower case.
Eventually I decided to try and make the conversion through the decorator:

```
def lt_dec(func):
    def _lt_lower(**kwargs):
        kwargs['lane_type'] = kwargs['lane_type'].lower()
        return func(**kwargs)
    return _lt_lower
```

Of course, I tried to test it - and it failed:

```
In [38]: @lt_dec
def test1(lane_type):
    print lane_type
   ....:     

In [39]: test1('Solid')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/homes/markg/<ipython-input-39-bb6cef5c7fad> in <module>()
----> 1 test1('Solid')

TypeError: _lt_lower() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

Obviously, I do not fully understand **kwargs substitution mechanism. I will really appreciate an explanation what I am missing and if there is an elegant solution for my problem.

**EDIT:**

I believe I should show some examples of function definitions for clarity:
Here is one method from a class

```
def add_polygon(self, points, lane_type, color):
```

A method from another class:

```
def __init__(self, points, lane_type, color, side=None):
```

A function

```
def lane_weight(lane_type):
```

Of course, for a function with 1 argument (I have several of those) the solution is simple

```
def lt_dec(func):
    def _lt_lower(lane_type):
        return func(lane_type)
    return _lt_lower
```

As is have stated above - is there is a generic solution that for all of the examples shown? (I am ready to accept No as answer)

Comment: "the solution is simple" - huh? that code doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `**kwargs` in function definition, you get **keyword arguments** (not positional arguments) as a dictionary:

```
>>> def lt_dec(func):
...     def _lt_lower(**kwargs):
...         print 'type(kwargs)=', type(kwargs)
...         print 'kwargs=', kwargs
...         kwargs['lane_type'] = kwargs['lane_type'].lower()
...         return func(**kwargs)
...     return _lt_lower
...
>>> @lt_dec
... def test1(lane_type):
...     print lane_type
...
>>> test1(lane_type='Solid')
type(kwargs)= <type 'dict'>
kwargs= {'lane_type': 'Solid'}
solid
```

---

```
>>> def lt_dec(func):
...     def _lt_lower(*args, **kwargs):
...         if args:
...             args = (args[0].lower(),) + args[1:]
...         elif 'lane_type' in kwargs:
...             kwargs['lane_type'] = kwargs['lane_type'].lower()
...         return func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return _lt_lower
...
>>> @lt_dec
... def test1(lane_type):
...     print lane_type
...
>>> test1('Solid')
solid
>>> test1(lane_type='Solid')
solid
```

**UPDATE**

Using [`inspect.getcallargs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs):

```
>>> import inspect
>>>
>>> def lt_dec(func):
...     def _lt_lower(*args, **kwargs):
...         kwargs = inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
...         if 'lane_type' in kwargs:
...             kwargs['lane_type'] = kwargs['lane_type'].lower()
...         return func(**kwargs)
...     return _lt_lower
...
>>> @lt_dec
... def test1(blah, lane_type):
...     print lane_type
...
>>> test1('foo', 'Solid')
solid
>>> test1('foo', lane_type='Solid')
solid
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not solve my generic problem. May there is no generic solutions?

Comment: @volcano Your problem will be fixed by this answer, could you please elaborate what your generic problem is, in the question?

Comment: @volcano, I added a code that handle both positional, keyword arguments. Is that what you want?

Comment: @volcano, I added another approach that use `inspect.getcallargs`.

Comment: @falsetru, loved the *inspect* approach; infortunately, it's too heavy. But I am greatfull for the idea. You've been a huge help

Comment: @volcano, NOTE: The second code work only when `lane_type` is the first parameter.

Comment: @falsetru, that is obvious, I am working on decorator with argument that defines position. I will post it when it's ready - but I still owe you for the idea :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45790/discussion-between-volcano-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 0):

This is the version of decorator that reduces impact of *inspect* by using it at decoration time - and not at the execution time. The execution impact is still relatively high - but 100 times lower than in the original decorator you proposed (just FYI)

```
def lane_type_lower(func):

    def _conv_pos(*args, **kwargs):
        args = list(args);
        args[pos] = args[pos].lower()
        return args, kwargs

    def _conv_kw(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['lane_type'] = kwargs['lane_type'].lower()
        return args, kwargs

    insp = inspect.getargspec(func)
    try:
        pos = insp.args.index('lane_type')
        conv_func = _conv_pos
    except ValueError:
        conv_func = _conv_kw

    def _lane_type_lower(*args, **kwargs):
        args, kwargs = conv_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return _lane_type_lower
```